# How to enumerate shared folders with ACLs?

Tags: windows-server-2003, access-control-list, directory, share

Does anybody know how to get the list of locally shared folders with ACLs and export the list to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Powershell to do this.  `gwmi -class win32_share` will get a list of shares.  This [guy's script](http://www.peetersonline.nl/wp-content/get-mysharepermissions.txt) will help you retrieve the permissions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll give it a shot. What I've tried is Sharenum from Sysinternals, it seems to be working, but there are some issues in windows server 2003 domain.